Issues Deploying Next.js and Prisma Project with MongoDB to Vercel
I'm encountering issues deploying my Next.js project, which uses Prisma and MongoDB, to Vercel. The project works fine locally, but when I deploy it to Vercel, I get the following error:
at 8428 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:1:3202)
at t (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
at 5857 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:1:825)
at t (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
at r (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:1:3644)
at /vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:1:3682
at t.X (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:1206)
at /vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:1:3657
at Object.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:1:3709)
> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1268:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

Added a postinstall script to package.json:
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "prisma generate"
}


erified that the DATABASE_URL is correctly set in Vercel.
Checked the detailed logs in Vercel, but the error persists.
Prisma Schema:
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Course {
  id          String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  clerkId     String
  name        String
  description String?
  imageUrl    String?
  price       Float?
  isPublished Boolean @default(false)

  categoryId String?   @db.ObjectId
  category   Category? @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])

  attachments Attachment[]
  chapters    Chapter[]
  purchases   Purchase[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@index([categoryId])
}

Prisma Client Instantiation:
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prismaClientSingleton = () => {
  return new PrismaClient();
};

declare const globalThis: {
  prismaGlobal: ReturnType<typeof prismaClientSingleton>;
} & typeof global;

const prisma = globalThis.prismaGlobal ?? prismaClientSingleton();

export default prisma;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') globalThis.prismaGlobal = prisma;

Main Page Code:
import prisma from '@/lib/prisma';

export default async function Home() {
  const courses = await prisma.course.findMany({
    select: {
      id: true,
      name: true,
    },
  });

  return (
    <main className="text-2xl">
      {courses.map((course) => (
        <p key={course.id}>{course.name}</p>
      ))}
    </main>
  );
}


Additional Information:
The project works perfectly fine locally.
The MongoDB connection string is correct and accessible.
All dependencies are up to date.
Question:
What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it to successfully deploy my Next.js and Prisma project with MongoDB to Vercel?
